# XslLoadException - This method has the same name and parameter types as another method in this class

Tags: c#, xml, xls

I have an XML file and I have an XSL translator file that came with it which can be used to translate the XML file into an xml file using the NAXML standard format.  For some reason, though, I am getting an exception when I call the Load function in the XslCompiledTransform

```
using System.Xml.Xsl;
```

Problematic block of code:

```
XslCompiledTransform xlstProcessor = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings();
        settings.EnableScript = true;
        System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("C:\\tlog2naxml.xslt");
        System.Xml.XmlResolver resolver = new System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver();
        xlstProcessor.Load(reader, settings, resolver); //Exception occurs here.
        xlstProcessor.Transform(@"C:\vperiodrept.xml", @"C:\test.xml");
```

I have tried different variations of these parameters but I keep getting this exception.  When I look at the definitions for the XslCompiledTransform class, I do not see any duplicate method signatures.  This is a standard .net class so I wouldn't expect to find any.  If anyone has any ideas what might be causing this I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Ae there extension scripts in the XSLT source code? (I'm asking because you set `EnableScript` to true.)

Comment: Yes it uses javascript.  If I don't add the settings with the EnableScript property set to true, I will get an exception during the transform saying scripts aren't enabled.  Interestingly, that means XslCompiledTransform.Load(string styleSheetUri) seems to work fine...but unfortunately I can't use that.  I need the one with settings.

Comment: Then your duplicate function might actually be in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the scripts in the XSLT you're loading, not with the `XslCompiledTransform` class; this exception's thrown when the compiler is compiling the scripts in the transform, and it's encountering two methods in the script that have the same signature.  The first thing I'd look at is includes - I don't know for certain, but I'd bet the compiler's probably not smart enough to recognize when you've included the same file twice.

Comment: I looked into xslt files and found the duplicate method it was crashing on.  My thanks to both you and @Tomalak.

Comment: @Hagelt18: I'll give the +1 on your behalf. ;-)